# How to define a function only for integers

Tags: plotting, functions, discrete

I want to create a function which only accepts integers. if a value other than integers are given it should output zero. This is what I've tried so far. I'm trying to do some discrete time signal experiments like time shifting.

specifically i want to create a function **y[n] = u[n] - u[n-5]**
and create another using it, **x[n] = y[n/2] + 2 y[n/2-1/2]**
so that i can get the following graph,

Here's my copy paste-able code: https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/a0b8ba05-a8cc-4cae-a075-6435e301d41a

[image: the function i need]

[image]

Comment: For example, use IntegerQ, for example: gamma[n_] := If[IntegerQ[n], (n - 1)!, 0]. You shouls also look at gamma[n_Integer] := (n - 1)!.

Comment: Thank you! so I was able to define **y[n_] := If[IntegerQ[n], UnitStep[n] - UnitStep[n - 5], 0]**

Comment: y[_] = 0; y[n_Integer] := UnitStep[n] - UnitStep[n - 5]

Comment: What about `y[n_ /; IntegerQ[n]] := ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please upvote my answer if you consider it helpful.
>
> I have been hurt many times.

In your code `y[n_Integer] := (UnitStep[n] - UnitStep[n - 5]);`, `y[n]` is only defined when its variable is `Integer`. That means if the variable of `y[n]` is a `fractional number` it outputs nothing. So please refer to my following code:

```
y[n_] := If[FractionalPart[n] == 0, UnitStep[n] - UnitStep[n - 5], 0]
DiscretePlot[{y[n/2] + 2 y[n/2 - 1/2]}, {n, -2, 12}, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.02], Red]]
```

[image]